# Getting Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher

Tags: java

I looked at other answers and I added the dependency to my gradle:

```
dependencies {
// other dependencies
    implementation 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3' 
}

however I am still getting the error, not sure why or what to do next
```

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your gradle project after adding this dependency?

Answer (score -1):

Use Maven to resolve this dependency automatically for you, or download it manually from Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.

Comment: How would I use maven to automatically resolve it? Sorry I am new to Java